# how to make zswap on hdd

Tags: ubuntu, partitioning, swap, zram

I run Lubuntu and have a partition from an old Ubuntu install, which i want to use for a zswap, or if that is difficult for a plain swap.

```
Disk /dev/sda: 298.1 GiB, 320072933376 bytes, 625142448 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x770a466d

Device     Boot     Start       End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sda1            2048  31459327  31457280    15G 27 Hidden NTFS WinRE

/dev/sda2  *     31459328  31664127    204800   100M  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sda3        31664128 349417344 317753217 151.5G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

/dev/sda4       349417470 625141759 275724290 131.5G  5 Extended

/dev/sda5       349417472 420357567  70940096  33.8G 83 Linux

/dev/sda6       621518848 625141759   3622912   1.7G 82 Linux swap / Solaris

/dev/sda7       420358144 621506559 201148416  95.9G 83 Linux

Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition table entries are not in disk order.

The primary GPT table is corrupt, but the backup appears OK, so that will be used.
```

I want to use 4Gb of sda5 for my swap/zswap. sda7 carries my Lubuntu. The current swap is too small for 4Gb of memory and it is at the end of my Lubuntu, so I am afraid to expand it backwards.

Comment: you can [install zram](https://askubuntu.com/q/174579/253474) instead of zswap, and use the swap partition as normal. It'll have lower priority than zram by default

Comment: I still need to have a 4gb swap as I like to hibernate my laptop.